# How do you add localization to the Settings bundle under source code control

Tags: ios, version-control, localization, settings.bundle

I am trying to localize my Settings.bundle. There does not appear to be anything in Xcode 4 that allows you to add localization to the Settings.bundle similar to localizing a xib file. So I used finder to navigate to the Settings.bundle and copied the en.lproj directory to create directories in the bundle called fr.lproj and de.lproj. From there, you can modify the strings file to localize the titles in the Root.plist.

But the problem is that the new directory is not under source code control. If I try to add the directory to source code control, I get the following error: The operation could not be performed because the selection is invalid.

How can I resolve this problem and get the new settings.bundle directory under source code control?

[image: Below is an image of the localized directories I added to my Settings.bundle. As you can see, the question mark indicates that the directory is not under source code control]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is right. I can't explain why you are unable to add your new subfolders/files to source control. I have the exact same structure in an iOS project of mine and these files are under source control like all the others. I don't recall having difficulties adding them.

Have you tried using git commands directly to add them? The integration in XCode is great but in my experience there are time when you do have to use the command line for git.

Comment: ok, I used "git add fr.lproj". This seems to have worked although the directory went from a "?" status to a "M" status and it remained "M" even after committing the changes. However, I then merged to the master branch. Xcode crashed, but after I reloaded it, everything is now ok and the "M" status is no longer there.

Comment: Gawd, doesn't inspire confidence eh!

Answer (score 1):

Correct strings file format is:
"Title" = "title in correct language";

Pay attention "Title" from Root.Plist NOT "Identifier"